# XNA animation sprite from transparent to opaque

Tags: c#, animation, xna, opacity

I have problem with animate image, when transforming from transparent image to opaque image.

If I animate image from opaque image to transparent image, works fine.
But, if I animate image from transparent image to opaque image, It's non-functional.(that's problem)

Sample code:

**Animate from opaque to transparent: (all is OK, it's functional)**

```
//Define variables (in construct):

float AlphaTime = 3500f; // total animate time (at milliseconds)
float AlphaTimeSubtract = 3500f; // at milliseconds
Color color = Color.White;

//Update method:

AlphaTimeSubtract -= (float)(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds); // abate number of elapsed time (for milliseconds) 
color *= MathHelper.Clamp(AlphaTimeSubtract / AlphaTime, 0, 1);

//Draw merhod:
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, color);
```

**Animate from transparent to opaque : (that is problem, it is non-functional) !!!**

Result is invisible sprite!(it's wrong)

Correct result should be: animate sprite from transparent to opaque.

```
//Define variables (in construct):

float AlphaTime = 3500f; // total animate time (at milliseconds)
float AlphaTimeSubtract = 3500f; // at milliseconds
Color color = Color.White;

//Update method:

AlphaTimeSubtract -= (float)(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds); // abate number of elapsed time (for milliseconds) 
color *= MathHelper.Clamp(Math.Abs(AlphaTimeSubtract - AlphaTime ) / AlphaTime , 0, 1);

//Draw merhod:
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, color);
```

[MathHelper.Clamp()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.mathhelper.clamp.aspx)

`Math.Abs()`: return absolute value

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: colors multiplier  = float number from 0 to 1. 0 = transparent , 1 = opaque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :** *Sorry, I had the flash of inspiration late :)*

Your code doesn't work because when the `Update()` method is called the first time the *Alpha* of your color becomes `0`, because the value that `Math.Abs(AlphaTimeSubtract - AlphaTime ) / AlphaTime` returns is very closed to `0.0f` so then for whatever number you will multiply *color*, it remains `0`. Infact this problem didn't happen in the first case because the logic says to decrease it starting from `1.0f`. So in this case you have to decrease the alpha starting everytime from 255. So this should work:

```
//Initialize it to 0
float AlphaTimeSubtract = 0.0f;

//Then in the update method increase it (The inverse logic you used in the opaque --> transparent effect)
AlphaTimeSubtract += (float)(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds);
color = Color.White * MathHelper.Clamp(AlphaTimeSubtract / AlphaTime , 0, 1);
```

I modified the code to make it more easier compared to the first effect (opaque -> transparent).

Comment: thanks, but both samples doesn't work. I tryed control AlphaTimeSubtract vaule and color value (in process). Both values was right! But sprite has drawed like invisible. None animation. I am sure, that I haven't  "none" sintax mistake! Can be mistake at depiction in draw method?

Comment: Ok I edited my answer, I was completely wrong. I tried to explain what we was missing.